# how do i add ui-routing in angularjs app?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to angularjs,i want to add ui-routing to my app.In my there is some custom directive ,i use ui.router but its not working.
i set it up on plunker
here is my index.html:

```
   <head>
     <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.10" data-semver="1.2.10" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
   <script src="app.js"></script>
   <script src="aboutCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="homeCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="myAppCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="searchDirective.js"></script>
   </head>

  <body>
     <div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
      <header ng-include="'nav.html'"></header>
      <div ui-view></div>
    <footer ng-include="'footer.html'"></footer>
     </div>
  </body>
```

how can i make this working.

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1J0Z7VScSkV5lckzmUBr?p=preview

Comment: Angular 1.2 seems like an odd choice to use with the latest ui-router. Also, some of your JS files are attempting to use a module named "app" which has not been defined

Comment: @Phil could you please suggest which version i should used and i now change the app to myApp